# Django int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'QueryDict'

Tags: python, django

I have a view which displays a form and saves the same form. There is no problem showing the view but when saving I get this following error:

*int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'QueryDict'*

Here is my code:

**MODEL:**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, db_index=True, unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='categories')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
            super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('wallet:category_details', args=[self.id])
```

**VIEW:**

```
@login_required
def category_create(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        category_create_form = CategoryCreateForm(request.POST)
        if category_create_form.is_valid():
            new_category = category_create_form.save(commit=False)
            new_category.user = request.user
            new_category.save()
            return render(request, 'category/done.html')
    else:
        category_create_form = CategoryCreateForm()
    return render(request, 'category/create.html', {'category_form': category_create_form})
```

**FORMS:**

```
class TransactionCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    field_order = ['name', 'type', 'wallet', 'category', 'date', 'amount', 'notes', ]

    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = ('name', 'type', 'wallet', 'category', 'date', 'amount', 'notes',)

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TransactionCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['wallet'] = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=[(wallet, str(wallet)) for wallet in Wallet.objects.filter(user=user)])
```

How should I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your form's `__init__` method specifies a `user` argument, which you're not providing when instantiating it. Create your form with:

```
category_create_form = CategoryCreateForm(user)
```

or, in the `POST` branch,

```
category_create_form = CategoryCreateForm(user, request.POST)
```

Well, assuming the actual class looks like the differently named form class you posted. Basically, look at what parameters your form requires.